# Is there a function lock for an Apple keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp

I am using Windows 7 on a Mac in my office. How can I tweak to ALWAYS use the function key instead of the "rewind, fast forward, play/pause, mute" feature for the F7-F12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using bootcamp, there is a setting for this under the Bootcamp options in Windows.

Comment: Thx, it works. Awesome!